# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{-u^{\alpha}x}\mathrm{d}u$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to know the value of this integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{-u^{\alpha}x}\mathrm{d}u$$

where $\alpha>0$, $x>0$.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a guess, but I would be very surprised if the integral was actually elementary.

Comment: Please I don't understand

Comment: It looks like [the Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) might be of use here (after a few substitutions).

Comment: Why do you need its exact value?  Perhaps an approximation would suffice?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any general form. However, for $\alpha=0$ we have $I(0)=e^{-x}$, for

$\alpha=1$ we have $I(1)=\dfrac1{1+x}$ , for $\alpha=2$ we have $I(2)=\sqrt\pi\cdot e^{^\tfrac1{4x}}\cdot\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}\cdot\text{erfc}\bigg(\dfrac1{2\sqrt x}\bigg)$,

and for $\alpha\!=\!\dfrac12$ we have $I\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)=1-\sqrt\pi\cdot~e^{^\tfrac{x^2}4}\cdot\dfrac x2\cdot\text{erfc}\dfrac x2\quad$ Deriving the first two results

should be trivial. For the latter two, see [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) and [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). The cases

$\alpha=3$ and $\alpha=\dfrac13$ involve [Airy functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function), [Anger functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anger_function), [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), and [Weber 

 functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_function). The rest, [hypergeometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) series. Negative values of $\alpha$ involve [Meijer G-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function).

As I said, I see no discernible pattern.

Comment: well i will learn, but can I use this $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{x}}dt=\GAMMA(1+\frac{1}{x})$?

Comment: @kacou: Only for $\alpha=2$ and $\alpha=\dfrac12$ , because, in that case, by [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) in the exponent and making a change in variable, the term in *u* alone vanishes completely. The only way to use the $\Gamma$ function is if you were to settle for an approximation, instead of an exact closed form expression, which might probably turn out to be not such a bad idea after all.

Answer (score 0):

Case $1$: $\alpha\leq1$

Then $\int_0^\infty e^{-u}e^{-u^\alpha x}~du$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^nu^{\alpha n}e^{-u}}{n!}du$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n\Gamma(\alpha n+1)}{n!}$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#definite_integrals)

Case $2$: $\alpha\geq1$

Then $\int_0^\infty e^{-u}e^{-u^\alpha x}~du$

$=\int_0^\infty e^{-u^\frac{1}{\alpha}}e^{-xu}~d\left(u^\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}e^{-u^\frac{1}{\alpha}}e^{-xu}~du$

$=\int_0^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nu^{\frac{n+1}{\alpha}-1}e^{-xu}}{\alpha n!}du$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\Gamma\left(\dfrac{n+1}{\alpha}\right)}{\alpha x^\frac{n+1}{\alpha}n!}$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#definite_integrals)

Comment: Well I'll learn, but I want to know if I can do this:

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}e^{-u^{\alpha}x}du=\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-u}-1+1)e^{-u^{\alpha}x}du=\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-u}-1)e^{-u^{\alpha}x}du+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^{\alpha}x}du$ and applying finite increassing in the first integrale and using the inequality $\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha}e^{-u^{a}c}du=\frac{1}{ac^{\frac{\alpha+1}{a}}}\gamma (\frac{\alpha+1}{a})$ in the second. And integration by part in the first integrale and use again the equality above. for the finite increassing I wrote in the first integrale like this:$e^{-u}-1=-ue^{-c}$ where $c\in]0,u[$ is it right?